# How do I activate a killstreak reward?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-ghosts

During the online play in CoD: Ghosts, after getting a killstreak reward which button should I press to activate that reward?

Comment: I think perhaps you mean kill streak reward rather than perk?

Comment: @TZHX: Yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

When you meet the conditions for a kill streak reward, the icon for it will appear in the bottom right corner around a representation if the D pad.

Press the corresponding button to activate it. I believe it's usually the down or left button.

Comment: Down and Up usually select the Killstreak, then left or right uses it. Not 100% sure.

Answer (score -2):

its the left button on the d-pad.